# How can I pass single options to push/pull of gitpython?

Tags: python, gitpython

The signature of many `Repo`-functions includes `**kwargs`, of which the documentation says, that you can pass arguments to the underlying wrapped git command. However, there is no place for `*args`. In order to pass flag-like arguments like `--all`. I would have expected them to be passed like `my_remote.pull('all')`. So, for instance, how would you pass `--all` to the pull function of `Remote`?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is to pass `<argument>=True` as part of the `**kwargs`. So, in the special case, this would be `my_remote.pull(all=True)`.

Comment: Wow, that's confusing. I expected to be using `push_args = {"--atomimc":None}` then passing it as `**push_args`, and was trying to figure out why nothing happened.